# Insert data into 2 tables using first table ID

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I've two tables in my `joomla 2.5` site component that trying to inset two tables and first table ID should be second table  `foreign-key`.

```
Table: MYTABLE
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  mytab_id  |  mytab_name | mytab_country  |  mytab_city  |  
-------------------------------------------------------------

 Table: YOURTABLE
    -------------------------------
    |  yourtab_id  |  group_name | 
    -------------------------------
```

`mytab_id` is `auto increment` value and that should insert to second table `yourtab_id` as  `foreign-key`.

How should I insert data to both tables as first table id value to second table  id.

I've tried below code but it doesn't work.

```
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO #__mytable (mytab_name, mytab_country, mytab_city) VALUES ('". $mytab_name."',".$mytab_country.",'".$mytab_city."'); ";
    $db->setQuery( $insert_query );
    $db->query();

    $insert_query2 = "INSERT INTO #__yourtable (yourtab_id, group_name) VALUES (".LAST_INSERT_ID().", 2);";
    $db->setQuery( $insert_query2 );
    $db->query();
```

Thanks,

Comment: Try $db->insertid() insted of LAST_INSERT_ID()!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This,

In Joomla you can get the last insert id using

```
 $db->insertid();
```

For details about [Joomla DB Queries](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase), Also try to use more standards in your query.

```
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

     // Insert columns.
     $columns = array('mytab_name', 'mytab_country', 'mytab_city');
     // Insert values.
     $values = array($db->quote($mytab_name), $db->quote($mytab_country), $db->quote($mytab_city));

    // Prepare the insert query.
    $query
         ->insert($db->quoteName('#__mytable'))
         ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
         ->values(implode(',', $values));

    // Set the query using our newly populated query object and execute it.
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->query();
```

You can make your query standards like [here](http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase)

Hope it helps..

Comment: IF I've has 3rd table that need to use first table (MYTABLE) id can I user 3rd `insert` query as 2nd one?

Comment: And thanks for your idea about 'standards' I'm still on testing level.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the available php function to achieve this

```
mysql_insert_id()
```

you can refer [Here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) For Documentation in php

Comment: Please don't recommend the deprecated mysql_* functions, instead use the newer mysqli alternative with its `$mysqli->insert_id` function.